# Invalid keys in object

Tags: javascript

I'm going to memoize a function, but I'm not sure if I should be careful with some specific parameters that could be passed to that function.

What are the keys that an object can never have (invalid keys), but a function can receive as arguments?

I can't think of any. Even `null` and `undefined` are valid object keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no invalid keys, because object keys in Javascript are stored as strings.

Even when you use a non-string value as a key, that value is cast to a String.

You can see this with a simple object like `{a:2}`, if you define it as a key in another object, for example:

```
var b = {}; 
b[{a:2}] = 2;
```

You can see that `{a:2}` will be cast into the string `"[object Object]"`.

Similarly, using `null` or `undefined` as keys would actually result in keys `"null"` and `"undefined"`.

Comment: @alexandernst: yes but they are still stored as strings

Comment: No, they are not. Make your tests and you'll see those are actually stored as whatever the type of the key is.

Comment: No, @alexandernst, they are casted into a `String`.

Comment: Ah, indeed, you're right. I just did a test. Why object keys are shown as not-a-string in chrome dev tools?

Comment: Because normal people do not use strange thing as keys :)